# String manipulation - getting file name from absolute file path

Tags: string, tcl

I have a variable containing a path to a file, that I obtain from the `tk_getOpenFile` function, the `$file` variable would be something like this:

```
/home/usr/Documents/Plugin-2-Linux.pdpk
```

I need some sort of split to get only the `Plugin-2-Linux`. Please note that the path may not be the same every time. So what I need is to get the string between the last `/` and the `.pdpk` and put it in another variable: `$filename`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set filename [file rootname [file tail $file]]
```

`file tail` returns the part after the last `/` (not counting trailing `/`s), and `file rootname` the part before the last `.`.

[man page for file](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm)